# Today Extension UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios8, nsnotificationcenter, today-extension

My app has a section with a daily quote, and this quote is pulled in from a webpage on the internet.  I have been trying to add in the quote using a Today Extension, so it could be viewed there, but the extension constantly shows up blank.

I have added the Today Extension File with storyboard, and in the implementation file for the code I have:

```
#import "TodayViewController.h"
#import <NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h>

@interface TodayViewController () <NCWidgetProviding>

@end

@implementation TodayViewController


-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Today's Scripture";
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 50);
    [reader loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.316apps.com/testingdailyreader.html"]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];
    // timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];




}

@end
```

However, all I get is a blank row that says 'Unable to Load' in the Notification Center.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same problem right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I transitioned from UIWebView to WKWebView.

Note: There is no property like UIWebView that you can drag onto your storyboard, you have to do it programatically.

Make sure you import WebKit/WebKit.h into your header file.

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
```

Here, the implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;
@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.productURL = @"http://www.URL YOU WANT TO VIEW GOES HERE";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.productURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   //[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.316apps.com/testingdailyreader.html"]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];

    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];  
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    _webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
    }
@end
```